# C++ program starts and hangs without error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, terminal

Being used to an IDE holding your hand I am stuck and don't know where to start searching for a solution. I don't even know what this type of problem is called...
The program runs successfully using Xcode, but when compiled and run on a Raspberry Pi it compiles successfully and starts but does not give any output or error.

I have tried removing everything except headers and main containing:

```
std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
```

Still no output.
Compiled using:

```
g++-4.7 -I include -I include/interface -I /usr/local/ssl/include -I /home/pi/gateway/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.5 -I /home/pi/gateway/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.5/cppconn -I /home/pi/gateway/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.5/driver -l mysqlcppconn -lwiringPi -lpthread -ldl -L/home/pi/gateway/live -std=c++11 -D PRODUCTION -o Gateway main.cpp src/*.cpp /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a;
```

3.6mb of memory is being used but CPU usage is 0%.

Edit:
By pure luck I found the problem, a static member object with a waiting callback in its constructor included through one of the headers. The question remains, where would one start troubleshooting? I'd rather not rely on luck next time! Commenting out one header at a time would result in all sorts of errors, so would removing compilation flags. I've included the minimal amount of code compiling successfully using the flags above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include "lightdevice.h"
#include "websocketserver.h"
#include "errorlog.h"
#include "debuglog.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Why is this not printing?" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I'd try each of those headers in turn.

Comment: Can you post your actual code in full?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What do mean by try each of them? How?

Comment: @cat The codebase is unfortunately too large for that...

Comment: Also try to remove the libs first - when you only print a message, you sure don't need to link with mysql, threads, ssl etc. (and comment out all the includes except iostream just to see if the main will show the message)

Comment: And if still nothing, you can also try to replace the std streams with printf (requires less machinery).

Comment: Where are you expecting the error to come up? Does your program open a console, are you running it under pidora or some other pi os?

Comment: Have you ever had any program you've written working on it before? If not start with the simplest possible "hello world" example for the Pi you can find and get that working first. Then slowly transform that into what you're doing now until it stops working.

Comment: @E.Maskovsky Removing the libs would cause all sorts of error since the included headers rely on them. Since I don't know if it's one of the libs causing the problem or something I've done, would you still remove them?

Comment: @Ben It's running in a terminal window, on Raspbian. Removing everything in main except a std::cout call, I am expecting it to show some sign of life.

Comment: @tukra Absolutely, previous versions have worked like they are supposed to. Unfortunately I've made too many changes at once, therefore I have no idea what could be causing the problem.

Comment: One of your include files probably does something that causes an endless loop. For example, something like `int deadlock() { while (1); return 0; } int j = deadlock();`.

Comment: Either printf-Debugging (adding printf all over the place to narrow it down) or get gdb running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running in a debugger, these threads can be inspected.  Look at the call stacks and find the objects which are being created.

Comment: Thank you, now I have somewhere to start!